# Xlxswriter - Change Date format from str to date

Tags: python, datetime, xlsxwriter

I am having trouble changing the date format of date column in the dataframe i created using Xlsxwriter. The current format is 3/31/2016  12:00:00 AM, which i thought python is reading a date and adding a time to it. I would like the format to simply be dd/mm/yyyy with know time associate with it for all of column A.

Here is my code:

```
date_format= workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'mmm d yyyy'})
date_time= dt.datetime.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
worksheet.write_datetime(0,0, date_time, date_format)
```

The error message i get is : TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.date' object but received a 'str'

Answer (score 1):

### `datetime.strftime` is for converting datetimes into strings

You are not giving it a datetime object to convert.

```
from datetime import datetime
today = datetime.today()   # this returns a datetime object
today.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") # this returns a string
datetime.strftime(today, "%m/%d/%Y") # alternative way to call it
```

### However, you actually need to pass a datetime object to `worksheet.write_datetime`

So in my example it would be like this

```
today = datetime.today()
date_format= workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'mmm d yyyy'})
worksheet.write_datetime(0, 0, today, date_format)
```

### To parse a date from a string use date time.strptime

```
dateobj = date time.strptime(datestr)
```

Comment: The datetime i am trying to convert is my first column in my dataframe. The format it is currently in as follows: 4/30/1982  12:00:00 AM . What object do i give it to convert? I am not looking to use todays date. I tried the following but received an error: date2= df.datetime.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
format7= workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'mmm d yyyy'})
worksheet.write_datetime(0,0, date2, format7)